# How to align two composites in a parent composite without using widthHint and heightHint

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I want two composites (one below the other) inside a parent component.

This is how my code looks like:

```
Composite composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);

Composite rowComposite = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
rowComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
GridData gd1 = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false);
gd1.widthHint = 760;
gd1.heightHint = 240;
rowComposite.setLayoutData(gd1);

Composite columnComposite = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
columnComposite .setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
GridData gd2 = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false);
gd2.widthHint = 760;
gd2.heightHint = 240;
columnComposite .setLayoutData(gd1);
```

Here, I'm using `widthHint` and `heightHint` which is not recommended as the whole layout will be ruined when the user decides to change the system font or resolution.

How do i achieve the same without using `widthHint` and `heightHint`.

Comment: Third line is not valid.Please copy correct code. It will not compile

Comment: @Chandrayya G K updated.

Answer (score 3):

Removed the widthHint and heightHint from both composites and updated grid data as:

```
new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
```

The GridLayout has taken care of width and height.

Answer (score 0):

composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

Set layout of parent to GridLayout, which the first parameter is the number of columns and the second is whether or not the columns will have equal width.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to try [WidowBuilder Pro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/)
This will help you to build HMI rapidly