# How to set width for GridData?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, grid-layout

[image: layout]

I was building an UI by using `GridLayout`/`GridData`. The layout supposes to have 3 section, one is the `headingComposite`, one is the `leftEditorComposite`, one is the `rightEditorComposite`. But my problem here is, I dont want my `leftEditorComposite`/`rightEditorComposite`'s width layout be changed by the content. (like the name textbox, if the input get longer, then the `leftEdtiorComposite`'s width will become longer too.) Is there a way to make them as a fix size width? thanks a lot!

```
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false);
    mainComposite.setLayout(layout);

    scrolledComposite.setContent(mainComposite);

    GridData data = new GridData();
    data.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
    data.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    data.horizontalSpan = 2;
    headingComposite = new Composite(mainComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    headingComposite.setBackground(getBackground());
    headingComposite.setLayoutData(data);

    data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
    leftEditorComposite = new Composite(mainComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    leftEditorComposite.setBackground(getBackground());
    leftEditorComposite.setLayoutData(data);

    data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
    rightEditorComposite = new Composite(mainComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    rightEditorComposite.setBackground(getBackground());
    rightEditorComposite.setLayoutData(data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the size of each composite, you could provide a `widthHint` for both your `Composite` objects.

```
leftEditorComposite.widthHint = 200;
```

and

```
rightEditorComposite.widthHint = 200;
```

Alternatively, you can read this question, and hopefully you will get your answer:
[How to align two composites in a parent composite without using widthHint and heightHint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742107/how-to-align-two-composites-in-a-parent-composite-without-using-widthhint-and-he?rq=1)